# IronPython: Error when launching .py script from c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ironpython

I'm running into a similar problem as this guy: [IronPython : Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'unexpected token '=''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535931/ironpython-microsoft-scripting-syntaxerrorexception-unexpected-token)
Unfortunately, there we no answers on that thread.

This is my code:

```cs
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var scope = engine.CreateScope();
try 
{
     engine.ExecuteFile(String.Concat(Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName, "\\Client.py"), scope);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

And then here's the .py (that doesn't do anything yet, really):

```py
#imports
import os
import tempfile

#Test
print("Here we go.")
```

The abomination to get the full path for my python file was an attempt to check if it got the path wrong or couldn't find the file, wasn't the case but I left it there. Debugger shows that the path is correct. However, it always fails on `engine.ExecuteFile(...)`. and catches an exception that, according to the debugger is `null`. I got this error:

> Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException

and then goofed around with settings, changing Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Enable just my Code" from *checked* to *unchecked* which lead to me not getting the *SyntaxErrorException* anymore but instead it's now this, but it still fails at the same line, with an exception that is still `null`:

> IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll

At this point I don't know if I made a step in the right direction or went one back. Can anyone help with this?

EDIT: I need to correct this. There currently is an exception that states: "No module named os" instead of being just `null` which makes sense considering the exception type.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the Lib folder to my project folder and had the search path extended by it like this:

```cs
String projectPath = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();

var libs = new[]
{
    String.Concat(projectPath, "\\Lib")
};
var pySP = engine.GetSearchPaths();
foreach (String resource in libs)
{
    pySP.Add(resource);
}
```

following this thread: [IronPython: No module named json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348288/ironpython-no-module-named-json).

Then I undid the changes I made to the debugging settings, and lastly added NuGet packages. Maybe there is now redundance with the added search path and the newly added packages but I am not willing to test my luck and undo any of the changes. Here is my `.csproj` file, for anyone who might need it when in the same position:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IronPython" Version="2.7.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="IronPython.Interpreter" Version="2.7.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="IronPython.StdLib" Version="2.7.10" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```